# Portable Realtime bidirectional library that doesn't use HTTP procotol

Tags: sockets, websocket, real-time

Could you suggest a portable library for creating realtime bi-directional sockets that do not rely on the HTTP/S or any other plain text protocol? I'd like to send data up and down in the smallest chunks possible.

The protocol must support TLS

Everything to do with WebSockets is off the list.

Though portable, I'm specifically looking for something that will work in Python and Java (Android)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you google RTP you might find some interesting resources.  Among other things, this is what ip-telephony likes to use.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of RTP. I was looking low bandwidth transport libraries for PUSH notifications. These notifications are just less than 1KB so there's no need to go all out HAMMER TIME. I did have a custom plain socket method that I came up with but I wanted to look for something that's already out there because I keep refactoring mine.